# One table two model

Tags: orm, cakephp, model, controller

i have posts table
id
type enum(A,Q)
title
content

and i need controllers questions_controller and answer_controller to use
please lead the right way to

1-
make 2 models (question and answer) and use 'posts' as model's table

2-
use post model in questions_controller and answer_controller

Answer (score 0):

For me, it should be **one table has one model**

So better use
$uses = array('Post'); in your controllers.

**Update:**
As far I understood you want to filter the data depending from the type column. Actually your db model is wrong, because except if they are totally unrelated your answers need to belong to the question. This mean you need an extra column parent_id which will determine what is the parent node (question) and child nodes (answers).

If we have this assumption, then you can set a relation in the model like:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
   ...
   var $belongsTo = array(
      'Parent' => array('className' => 'Post','foreignKey' => 'parent_id', 'conditions' => 'Parent.parent_id IS NOT NULL')
   );
   ...
}
```

So you automatically have Post and Post->Parent. But I think that it would be better to have 2 tables - one which holds the questions and another the answers.

Comment: but every time then i will (CRUD) the data   
i must where the condition (type => A or Q)  so my idea was to escape it  any suggestions

Comment: Ok, I didn't understood your question. I will update my answer

Comment: thanks for help Nik  the idea to use 1 single merged table is to speed up the sql queries